# How to use PHP to get the element content of another page which was modified by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I want to use PHP to extract a span content by id of another outside page (http://www.abcd.com/a1.html). But unfortunately the span element was originally empty and was modified by the javascript of that page. If I use file_get_contents function and grep the content of the span id, I only get empty string since if content is filled by ajax script.

```
<!--   http://www.abcd.com/a1.html  -->
....
<div>This span content is:<span id="spanid"></span></div>
....

<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           cache: false,
           async: false,
               .....

           ret_val = ...  ;
           jQuery("#spanid").html(ret_val);

      });
</script>
```

Is there a way so that I can use PHP the extract the content of 'spanid' for each page from a set of web pages such as  http://www.abcd.com/a1.html,  http://www.abcd.com/a2.html, http://www.abcd.com/a3.html, http://www.abcd.com/a4.html   ?

Comment: Why not have JS do this and send it to the PHP sever?

Comment: Are you trying to scrape a page from PHP?  If so then your options are to look into using what's called a "headless browser" in your PHP code (which would execute the JavaScript internally and allow you to further interact with the modified DOM) or to reverse-engineer the target site's AJAX and make your own HTTP requests based on those.

Comment: @David I have face some issue like this. Could you provide more information about "headless browser" or "reverse-engineer" ? Any documentation for PHP or any programming language . Thank you

Comment: @ToujouAya for PHP: https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php - if you're open to other technologies, Python scrapy with this: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash does the job.

Comment: @SoufianeHassou thank